# Merge Tags [viewcomponents], [asp.net-viewcomponents] and [razor-viewcomponents]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I just asked a question regarding `ASP.NET Core`'s `ViewComponent` feature and found 3 tags which represent the feature:

- [viewcomponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewcomponents)

  - no documentation
- [asp.net-viewcomponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-viewcomponents)

  - "Questions regards viewComponents which were introduced with asp core"
- [razor-viewcomponents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/razor-viewcomponents)

  - "more powerfull version of partial views intended for making reusable rendering logic."

If we look at the `asp.net-core` tag naming convention:

- [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc)
- [asp.net-core-middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-middleware)
- etc

Shouldn't all these three tags be merged into a unique [asp.net-core-viewcomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-viewcomponent)?

They all have relatively low post counts at the moment as the feature is still in its infancy. This would easier to tackle now before they become more popular.

Comment: Ok, I just created a question exactly like this before finding this post. Will remove mine and focus on your post.

Comment: @Nkosi Well, [tag:viewcomponents] no longer exists!

Comment: Ok. cool. [tag:asp.net-core-viewcomponent] needs to have more posts that the others before a synonym suggestion will be allowed

Comment: Right. Will need to let some time pass so the system can update. Then there should be users with enough rep to be able to create and vote on the synonym. We've done all we can do for now. We can come back to this at a later time. Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: @Nkosi Done, all three tags have been extinguished (they only had 20-30 each). Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be considered done. All questions have been re-tagged into the new [asp.net-core-viewcomponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-viewcomponent) tag when properly used and had the tag removed when it was incorrectly used.